# Count the records in an Excel table whose start to end dates fall within a date range

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a table in my Excel Data Model with data like the following:

| Item | Inventory IN Date | Inventory OUT Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 9/1/23 | 9/6/23 |
| ABC | 9/1/23 | 9/4/23 |
| ABC | 9/1/23 | 9/5/23 |
| XYZ | 9/3/23 | 9/4/23 |
| XYZ | 9/3/23 | 9/5/23 |

I would like to create a pivot table (or some kind of report) that would take a date range as an input parameter and return a total count of items for each day within that range:

User selected range = 9/1/23 to 9/7/23

| Date | Item Count |
| --- | --- |
| 9/1/23 | 3 |
| 9/2/23 | 3 |
| 9/3/23 | 5 |
| 9/4/23 | 5 |
| 9/5/23 | 3 |
| 9/6/23 | 1 |
| 9/7/23 | 0 |

Is that possible in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an alternative solution, though the tags posted reflects about <kbd>PIVOT TABLE</kbd> which I am not aware to do it, is possible with <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> as well as with <kbd>Excel Formulas</kbd>, here is an attempted example how you could accomplish this task. Formulas used exclusively works with **`MS365`**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E4</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _dateRange,SEQUENCE(F2,,--F1),
     _count,MAP(_dateRange,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(x>=B2:B6)*(x<=C2:C6)))),
     VSTACK({"Date","Item Count"},HSTACK(_dateRange,_count)))
```

---

The above formula takes reference cell <kbd>F1</kbd> as input date parameter while <kbd>F2</kbd> as the number of days it needs to extend or count for, using the help of <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper function <kbd>MAP( )</kbd> .

Firstly we are creating a range of dates using the <kbd>SEQUENCE()</kbd> function, and then we are iterating the number of days with each date ranges using the help of <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper function <kbd>MAP( )</kbd> which iterates each ranges of <kbd>IN DATE</kbd> and <kbd>OUT DATE</kbd> to get the counts respectively.

---

Comment: This looks promising.  My data is in the Excel Data Model as a "Connection Only".  I don't have the actual table of data imported on a sheet anywhere.  Is it possible to reference the Data Model table instead of a table on a sheet?

Comment: You need to import the data into excel, to apply the above approach.

Comment: Is it possible to also include records that do not have an OUT date?  If they are still in inventory, the OUT date will be blank.

Comment: @Bruno71 then it would be like this `=LET(
     _dateRange,SEQUENCE(F2,,--F1),
     _count,MAP(_dateRange,LAMBDA(x,LET(a,B2:C8,b,FILTER(a,TAKE(a,,-1)<>""),SUM(--(x>=TAKE(b,,1))*(x<=TAKE(b,,-1)))))),
     VSTACK({"Date","Item Count"},HSTACK(_dateRange,_count)))` it excludes where the `OUT_DATE` is blank

Comment: Those results are the same as the previous.  I want to INCLUDE records where the OUT date is still blank.  So for a date of 'X'.... (X is between IN and OUT) - or- (X >= IN & OUT = <blank>)

Comment: Any ideas on how to `include` records with a blank OUT date?

Comment: A screenshot with what you have and expected output might help me, so i can try out with formulas

Comment: Using your original formula, here is the output vs what is expected. 
[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/7tQM5kP)